# Android Studio takes too much time to execute an app

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am using `Android Studio 2.0.0 beta 3` version and whenever i run an app it takes around 1m 30s to run minimum. I have experienced even upto 3m 50s delay for executing an app which is really frustrating. Below are few things that i have tried to fix this,

In app's gradle file,

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries=false
    incremental=true
    javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
}
```

In User/.gradle/gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Im using below version of tool, in build.gradle file outside app's module

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta3'
```

I have also enabled `Offline Mode` in Settings -> Gradle section. Please share your thoughts.

Edit:

System Details:

```
Intel I7
16gb RAM
Windows 8.1 Os 64-bit
```

> I also have 3 product flavors and 4 build types in the project.

**I even sometimes think android studio is much worse than eclipse. I have read gradle provides lot of great features. Does the gradle cost us this execution time to make those pros? or Is it just because of IntelliJ? Can someone who knows about this better explain.. which will help a lot of devs like me.**

Comment: Why do you need an 8 gig heap?

Comment: @SivakumarS Can you post you system configuration details ?

Comment: @cricket_007  Initially i tried with `2g`, i just made it to `8g` with an anxiety that it will make the studio faster :).

Comment: @AxeFox - i have updated my question with details. Thanks for reminding abt it.

Comment: If instant run is on it will add dependencies which take some more time to execute first time. Once you disable it, gradle will again execute as a new project which will take time to execute project again. Infact i have to wait more than 5 min sometimes.

Comment: @SivakumarS OMG! You've i7 with 16gRAM, and took more than a minute to build! Unbelievable! by the way, Is there any other process running in background ? Have you tried with `Android Studio 1.5 ` ? Check your process list, there might be some hot-process running. If the above things are false. then remove the customized line from the `build.gradle`, let it be as it was except the dependencies list.

Comment: Yesterday i having the same issue with one project in an MSI GT70 i7 16 Gb Ram Win 10 64 bits..my project delay almost 1 min in debugPublish....and 1 min in debugRelease..I clean my custom variant build and everything work faster

Comment: @AxeFox Yes, i have `Android Studio 1.5.1` as well which is a stable version. It is taking same time in that too. :(

Comment: @SivakumarS try running from the command line with ./gradlew assembleDebug --profile to see what steps are actually taking the longest time.

Comment: @SivakumarS I think the problem is not with `Android Studio`, but with the `gradle`. May be this will help you. http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2015/06/11/speeding-up-your-gradle-builds/

Comment: @kcoppock I will try that and write the results here. Thanks

Comment: @AxeFox - I have checked the process list already... couldn't find anything odd. And I will give it a try by removing the customized lines. let u guys know.

Comment: I tried to execute after removing customized lines and the result is the same.

Comment: how big is your project (including external libs)?

Comment: @pskink - My apk size comes around 14mb

Comment: How big is classes.dex inside your apk?

Comment: @pskink My app is a multidex app and it has 10 classes.dex. all of them combined occupies a size of 13mb

Comment: 13 MB of code is pretty much,  dont you think?  It cannot be compiled in just few seconds...

Comment: Okay. I thought gradle is capable of doing it fast... And i was also interested in knowing if there are any solutions.

Comment: Well I think it depends on how many dependencies do you have.